# Unable to create a fargate profile for the AWS EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I have an AWS EKS cluster named **xyz-cicd** in the regios Ohio(us-east-2) which I had created using the `eksctl` command like below:-

```
eksctl create cluster --name xyz-cicd --region us-east-2 --fargate
```

It took some time to create a cluster with a default profile however I want to create a new profile for the same cluster so I ran the following command which is giving me an error:-

```
vinod827@Vinods-MacBook-Pro cicd % eksctl create fargateprofile \
  --cluster xyz-cicd \
  --name cicd \
  --namespace cicd
Error: fetching cluster status to determine operability: unable to describe cluster control plane: ResourceNotFoundException: No cluster found for name: xyz-cicd.
{
  RespMetadata: {
    StatusCode: 404,
    RequestID: "c12bd05c-3eb6-40bf-a972-f1cba139ea9a"
  },
  Message_: "No cluster found for name: xyz-cicd."
}
vinod827@Vinods-MacBook-Pro cicd %
```

Please note there is no issue with the cluster name or region. The cluster does exists in this same region but not sure why the `eksctl` command is returning the error stating no cluster found with the same name. I can schedule a pod on the default profile if that were the case. Please advise, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your second command is missing the region parameter and therefore probably using a different region. That is why it not finding your cluster.